# Why i get Undefined error in getgrgid() function

Tags: c, file, unix, directory

Basically my code looks like this:

```
int main(int ac, char **av) {


    char *dir_name = get_dir_name(ac, av);
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    t_stat rd_stat;

    dir = opendir(dir_name);
    if (!dir) {
        perror("diropen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    t_group *group_info;

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            if (lstat(entry->d_name, &rd_stat) == -1) {
                perror("lstat");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if ((group_info = getgrgid(rd_stat.st_gid)) == NULL) {      
                perror("getgrgid() error");
            }
            printf(%s\n", group_info);
        
    }

    closedir(dir);
}
```

And i'm getting error while trying to decode group id to char* type:

> getgrgid() error: Undefined error: 0

I have no idea why this doesn't work, because everything worked well with user id

Comment: Not finding a matching group isn't considered an error, so it doesn't set `errno`.

Comment: It just returns `NULL` in that case.

Comment: When you use `ls -l` on that file, does it show a group name or does it show the group as a number?

Comment: [The official `getgrgid` reference](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getgrgid.html) will be useful to read.

Comment: BTW, you need to concatenate the directory name and `entry->d_name` when calling `lstat()`. Otherwise, it's looking for the file in the current directory, not `dir_name`.

Comment: @Barmar it shows as a number

Comment: So this is the expected result. There's no entry for the group ID in `/etc/group`, and `getgrgid()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: Side note: The line `printf(%s\n", group_info);` is missing a `"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getgrgid()` returns `NULL` when there's an error or when the group ID isn't found. You need to check `errno` to tell the difference.

Also, `group_info` is a structure, not a string, you can't print it with `printf()`. Get the `gr_name` member to print the group name.

```
            if ((group_info = getgrgid(rd_stat.st_gid)) == NULL) {
                if (errno) {  
                    perror("getgrgid() error");
                } else {
                    printf("Unnamed group %d\n", rd_stat.st_gid);
                }
            } else {
                printf(%s\n", group_info.gr_name);
            }
```